# Data Validation to Include Comma Character

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following short macro to assign Data Validation as a list of characters:

```
Sub DVList()
    With ActiveCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="a,b,c,d"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
    End With
End Sub
```

The macro works.

I want to modify the macro to include the comma character in the list.  I don't see how to do this because the comma is the list separator.

Am I stuck having to use worksheet cells to build the list??

Comment: @pnuts I don't know how to build =CHAR(44) into my Formula1 string

Comment: @pnuts It would be the same as simply type `,`...

Comment: @pnuts Writing `"a,b"` is absolutely the same as `"a"&Chr(44)&"b"`... But I noticed now: you are disregarding VBA.

Comment: @pnuts Ok, I thought it because you misused `CHAR` instead of `Chr`. Keep in mind that you can use `Chr` when you want to insert a unsupported character in VBA strings. `,` doesn't apply, it is valid within strings. Problem is that is a list separator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A far as I could test, you can't escape `,` in list.

But you can reference a range. You can build a range (in, eg, a hidden sheet), fill cells with all possibilities and make `Formula1 := "=HiddenSheet!A1:A10`.

Comment: I am marking this as ANSWER, but am using "pnuts" in my code.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What I am saying is that I tried your solution and it worked.  I therefore marked your response as ANSWER.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape!
To fix use alt+0130 to create "‚"
is the same picture of comma, but is different than 044
So it works!

My best regards from Brazil

Comment: Can you show an example on how you do it with `alt+0130`? Thanks in advance.