# Adding a data validation list where entries have commas

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am using this code to add a defined list to a cell.
The range of entries which I wish to populate this list have commas within their names.  The code then recognises this line as two or more items within the TempList string.  Is there a way to include the comma within the items and not have it split out?

```
Sub DefinedPartnerListPop()

   Dim rList As String
   Dim MyCol As Collection
   Dim i, n, k, j, a As Integer
   Dim TempList, Partner As String
   Dim WSHT, WSHT2 As Worksheet
   Dim Swap1, Swap2

   Set WSHT = Sheet1

   With WSHT
   a = WorksheetFunction.CountA("A1:A13")
   k = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) - a

   Set MyCol = New Collection
   For i = 1 To k
        If Len(Trim(.Range("B" & 13 + i).Value)) <> 0 And .Range("A" & 13 + i) <> "" Then
            On Error Resume Next
          Partner = .Range("B" & 13 + i).Text
            MyCol.Add Partner
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next i

    For n = 1 To MyCol.Count
        TempList = TempList & "," & MyCol(n)
    Next

    TempList = Mid(TempList, 2)

End With
With WSHT

.Range("B12").ClearContents: .Range("B12").Validation.Delete
With .Range("B12")
 With .Validation
'Call UnProtectChecklistSht
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=TempList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True

End With
End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use an internal *VBA* string as a DV criteria list.  *VBA* assumes that the comma separates the items of the DV list.
If you want to include the comma symbol in the DV list, you should put the list in an array cells and use that array of cells for the criteria.

See:

[My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722398/data-validation-to-include-comma-character)

Comment: is there no way to do in the vba code?  I can use a dynamic list on the cell range within name manager and although this works, it would be good to have the solution contained wholly within the macro.

Comment: @AC3 ............ ** I AGREE WITH YOU 100% **  ............there should be a way to define a different separator character for strings