# Data Validation with double values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to put a `DataValidation` formula in a Ccell which would allow me to choose between 2 double values.

Here is the code I have tried to use :

```
Sub ListeDeroulante()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim values1 As Double
    Dim values2 As Double
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim validationFormula As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("B198")
    values1 = -0.47762776914086
    values2 = -1.15182691509465

    rng.Validation.Delete

    validationFormula = values1 & "','" & values2

    With rng.Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=validationFormula
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With
End Sub
```

But when I use this code I get 4 different options between 0 the decimal part of `values1` and `1` and the decimal part of `values 2`. I've tried using the `xlValidateDecimal` but it doesn't allow me to put 2 different numbers in one cell.

Ultimately, I would like to retrieve 2 different values for each cell of a table and put a `DataValidation` between those 2 values for each cell. If anyone has an idea to solve this issue it would be very kind of you.

Comment: You are on a French system? Then your decimal separator is a comma. When you concatenate values1 and values2 the dot is replaced by a comma which is then interpreted as separator for the list. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18723773/16578424) for a solution

Comment: Yes I'm on a French system. I've read the topic you linked in your answer. Should i replace the comma in my values1 with alt+0130 ? Because I've tried to use alt+0130 or even Chr(44) but i still obtain the 4 different options in my data validation cell... I'm sorry I am really bad in VBA so maybe I am doing something wrong but I don't know what to change.

Comment: Why do you need VBA to add the validation list? The idea of the link is to put the values on a hidden sheet, name the range, e.g. lstDeroulante and then you can refer to that name in VBA: `Formula1:="=lstDeroulante"`

Comment: The fact is, ultimately, I'm using a function to calculate two values for a same cell in a tab. After that I want to create a DataValidation on the cell with the two values allowing me to choose between the two values. But, I would like to create this without putting the values elsewhere or in an other sheet if it is possible.